# Using WCF service with SignalR SelfHost

Tags: wcf, signalr

I am new to SignalR and I am sorry if this is a old question. If it is please let me know where it is. Please excuse me for my English.

I am working on following task.

I need to read MSMQ messages and publish a message to all subscribed clients. For this we want to do like below

Have a SelfHost SignalR. In this have a WCF service that continuously read MSMQ messaes. We want to pass the reply/response to various clients that subscribe via SelfHost SignalR. I googled a lot but cannot find nice and simple example of my scenario where you use SignalR SelfHost + WCF service that does something continuously and SelfHosted SignalR sends reply back to a simple clients like a Console application or WPF.

Please let me know if you know any link where I can find some information of how to do what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an example of the server initiating a broadcast in response to a non-client event, see the following:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20

Answer (score 0):

I created an Empty ASP.NET Web application. For that I added WCF Service, using Package Manager Console executed install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR, then added Hub class and Startup class. External client will call a method in my service, and then service broadcasts to all other clients